# If a solution to Ax=b does not have any nullspace components, why is it's norm minimum?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I have found a few references on the web stating:

If a solution, x, to Ax = b does not contain any nullspace components. Then the euclidean norm is a minimum.

My understanding of this is $x + n = x_0$, where $n \in N(A)$, and $Ax = Ax_0$, $||x||_2 < ||x_0||_2$.

One [reference (pdf link)](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs322/2007sp/notes/qr.pdf) I found states: "If x had any component in the null space, it could be subtracted without changing Ax, resulting in a smaller-norm solution."

I generally understand that, but can someone mathematically explain why the two norm is less? Couldn't the nullspace component be a negative vector, which would actually decrease the two norm? (causing all $x_1$, $x_2$, etc to be smaller values than without the null space component?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Any solution to $Ax=b$ (if it exists) can be written as $x=x_0+z$, where $z\in N(A)$ and $x_0\in N(A)^{\perp}$ and $x_0$ is that "solution without nullspace components". Since $x_0\perp z$, the Pythagorean theorem gives that $\|x\|^2=\|x_0\|^2+\|z\|^2$. The minimum-norm solution is hence attained for $z=0$.